# Javascript function not printing onto the console

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why the following is not being printed to the console? I cant understand what the error is ..can Some one help me debug the error.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/scenes/scene_world.js">
  //document.write("<button type='button' onclick='click();'>Click Me!</button>");
  //document.write("<input id='clickMe' type='button' value='clickme' onclick='lol();' />");
    console.log("lol");
  </script>
```

inside scene_world.js:

```
  function lol(){
  console.log("lol");
  }
```

Tired accessing it from outside like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/scenes/scene_world.js">
  //document.write("<button type='button' onclick='click();'>Click Me!</button>");
  //document.write("<input id='clickMe' type='button' value='clickme' onclick='lol();' />");

  </script>
  <script>
  document.write("<input id='clickMe' type='button' value='clickme' onclick='lol();' />");
  </script>
```

But it is giving me this error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: lol is not defined

Answer (score 4):

`script` tags with an `src` attribute cannot have inline content as well. You need to create a new script block for that.

Answer (score 2):

According to the official [w3c](/questions/tagged/w3c) html specification:

> If the src has a URI value, user agents must ignore the element's
>   contents and retrieve the script via the URI

For details see the <kbd>[Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1)</kbd>

Comment: see so i want to access a function inside scene_world.js so what should i do?

Answer (score 2):

From the **[w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html)**.

> If the src attribute is not set, user agents must interpret the
>   contents of the element as the script. If the src has a URI value,
>   user agents must ignore the element's contents and retrieve the script
>   via the URI.

Answer (score 1):

You should clear everything between the `<script>` tags with a `src` attribute and put your codes in a separate `<script>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/scenes/scene_world.js"></script>
<script>
document.write("<input id='clickMe' type='button' value='clickme' onclick='lol();' />");
</script>
```

See [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/eleham/1/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after your edit, `scene_world.js` is fine. Why use `document.write(..)`?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/scenes/scene_world.js">
</script>
<input id='clickMe' type='button' value='clickme' onclick='lol();'/>
```

Should work when button is clicked.

For direct call:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/scenes/scene_world.js">
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    lol();
</script>
```

Have you inserted those script tags inside `head` or `body`?

Comment: i just wanted to make it work in javascript. But with or without the script its not calling the function in scene_world.js. And document.write was being used in the main html file

Comment: i want it to based on click of a button. See still it is not calling the function in scene_world.js Is it because it cant recognize the function in this script tag?

Comment: even the direct call is giving me an error. Everything i wrote is proper isnt it?

Comment: Is the path to `scene_world.js` correct? Press `CTRL+U` in your browser, find this script tag and click on it's `src` attribute. It should show the source of `scene_world.js`.

Comment: Path and all are right. What i cannot figure out is why it is not invoking the function

Answer (score 0):

It was not printing on to the console because the function i tried invoking was inside another function. So it was not properly invoked. A careless mistake.